# Optimize query with many OR statements in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the best way to write query which will give equivalent result to this:

```
SELECT X,Y,* FROM TABLE
WHERE (X = 1 AND Y = 2) OR (X = 2235 AND Y = 324) OR...
```

Table has clustered index (X, Y).
Table is huge (milions) and there can be hundreds of OR statements.

Answer (score 5):

you can create another table with columns X and Y
and insert the values in that table and and then join with the original table

```
create table XY_Values(X int, Y int)

Insert into XY_Values values
(1,2),
(2235,324),
...
```

Then

```
SELECT X,Y,* FROM TABLE T
join XY_Values V
on T.X=V.X
and T.Y=V.Y
```

You could create an index on (X,Y) on XY_Values , which will boost the performance

You could create XY_Values as a table variable also..

Comment: Good idea, do you have any knowledge about performance gain with this approach?

Comment: @watbywbarif: You could create an index on (X,Y) on the new table, which will boost the performance

Comment: @watbywbarif: This approach will have a performance advantage over the query with OR conditions as it can use index on both the tables, more importantly, easy to maintain and  readable

Comment: A question, if you have X and Y only in the second, helper table, why do you need an index? I'm really curious. I thougth before, that in this case it is kind of does not matter because it is just a duplicate then of the table.

Comment: I see no benefit of index on temp table. I will do some testing in following weeks and see how big is the performance gain over original OR approach.

Comment: @AndrásOttó:, watbywbarif: If the data in the helper table is not big enough, in our case may be in thousands , there may not be any significant  performance difference.. But as I mentioned earlier, this is more readable and maintainable

Comment: @JoeGJoseph: I mean, if you have two column in a table, and you make an index on that two column, is not like you have the data duplicated? So on this way a table scan is kind of index seek. Even more if you filled the helper table with ordered data. For sure, if there would be col3,col4,col5... in the helper table it would be a benefit, but since in the table there are only X and Y, just like on the index it does not seem to be a performance gain.

Comment: @AndrásOttó: Good thinking..but searching on index would be faster than on a table..

Answer (score 3):

I think you can fill up a temp tables with the hundreds of X and Y values, and join them.

Like:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
X int,
Y int
)
```

Prefill with this with your search requirements and join then.

(Or an other physical table which saves the search settings.)

Answer (score 3):

this will do better

```
select t.* 
from table t
join (select 1 as x,2 as y
      union
      ...) t1 on t.x=t1.x and t.y=t1.y
```

Comment: Interesting approach, how would performance of this compare to creation of temp table?

Comment: I do not think there will be any performance difference between them. Or if .. very small in favor of this (not creating a table / not inserting into it).But this will apply on big temp tables. But you wanted a single query and this is the way.

Comment: I think there is a high risk of a very bad performance. There is a large SQL statement that needs to be parsed. There are hundreds of unions, which may be very slow. I think the original statement which just adds the values with OR is still better.

Comment: No way .. if the target table is big you are far from right. Hundreds of unions will be parsed almost instant. Only if you work on a remote server and you have network issues this might be slow.

Comment: I would agree that parsing is not a big problem as it is done only once, I guess that performance of this is close to temp table, but to tell which is better some testing is required.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using too many or statements the execution plan wont use indexes.
It is better to create multiple statements and merge the result using union all.

```
SELECT X,Y,* 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (X = 1 AND Y = 2) 
union all
SELECT X,Y,* 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (X = 2235 AND Y = 324) 
union all...
```